# Default Jhipster 6.7.1 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jhipster, liquibase, sqlexception

I used Jhipster 6.7.1 to generate a monolith angular/spring boot app. I chose H2 with on-disk memory for development and MySQL database for production. It all went well.

I then ran `jhipter mvnw` command and it all seemed to be ok.

Then I tested if I can go to production running `mvnw -Pprod`. To my dismay, I got the following error :

```
Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [base/config/LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

What can I do to fix this ?

Comment: Check how you configured datasource in application-prod.yml, does it match how you configured mysql?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I updated the password, but now I have another error : `java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed`

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I have tried to run my app using docker and it worked fine. it is a problem with my database somehow. I will try a clean install on MySQL.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I was able somehow to make it work : I jammed in `&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` in the jdbc url in application-prod.yml and it all worked out. thank you for help